# Support for the selected Android target SDK android-undefined is not verified. Your Android app might not work as expected

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nativescript

code output is not shown on my device..
can anyone help me out?

Comment: looks like you're trying to build against an invalid android version

Answer (score 0):

Where is your location?

seems nativescript don't work properly in some countries.

Use Vpns both on mobile and PC